# How can I print polymorphic values in Standard ML?

Tags: functional-programming, polymorphism, printing, sml

Is there a way to print polymorphic values in Standard ML (SML/NJ specifically)?  I have a polymorphic function that is not doing what I want and due to the abysmal state that is debugging in SML (see [Any real world experience debugging a production functional program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393492/any-real-world-experience-debugging-a-production-functional-program)), I would like to see what it is doing with some good-ol' `print`'s.  A simple example would be (at a prompt):

```
fun justThisOnce(x : 'a) : 'a = (print(x); x);
justThisOnce(42);
```

Other suggestions are appreciated.  In the meantime I'll keep staring the offending code into submission.

#### Update

I was able to find the bug but the question still stands in the hopes of preventing future pain and suffering.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no way to print a polymorphic value.
You have two choices:

- Specialize your function to integers or strings, which are readily printed.  Then when the bug is slain, make it polymorphic again.
- If the bug manifests only with some other instantiation, pass `show` as an additional argument to your function.  So for example, if your polymorphic function has type

  ```
  'a list -> 'a list
  ```

  you extend the type to

  ```
  ('a -> string) -> 'a list -> 'a list
  ```

  You use `show` internally to print, and then by partially applying the function to a suitable `show`, you can get a version you can use in the original context.

  It's very tedious but it does help.  (But be warned: it may drive you to try Haskell.)

Answer (score 1):

**Only in MOSML**: Merely for debugging purposes, use the `printVal` function. Note that this function is only available in toplevel mode, it will cause an error when you try to compile your program.

**Edit**: In that case, I'm afraid there is no general solution, you need to translate your values explicitly to strings, and print those. See other answer for good suggestions.

Comment: Looks like printVal is only available in Moscow ML http://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/mosmllib/Meta.html.  Unfortunately I'm stuck with SML/NJ, but thanks for the suggestion.